# onblur not working for anchor-tag in Chrome

Tags: jquery

onblur or onfocusout events not working Google Chrome. but it works fine in every other browsers

```
<HTML><HEAD>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#lPass').blur(function() {  
                alert('s');
            });
        });
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY >
    <a id="lPass" href="##">ss</a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it is readable. Be sure to include 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. How are you testing it?

Answer (score 0):

No idea whether this is it, but my first suspect would be this line:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
```

replace it by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and see whether it works then.